# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #4](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/4) on Academia has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Bryan Krause]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/4) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5098297900400640).

Comment: Congratulations, Bryan!

Comment: Two awesome candidates in this election, thanks to both of you for running!

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thank you! and thank you very much for standing. All your efforts here and especially your focus towards curation are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

Congratulations to Bryan for joining us and a big thank you to both candidates for participating in this hot summer (but also winter) election!